# Field missing from 'Quick Field Calculation Bar' in attribute table

Tags: qgis

QGIS 3.22. Using utf-8 shp files for layers.

I have a table, which includes a field 'uuid'. I wish to populate the field using the 'Quick Field Calculation Bar'. But the field does not appear in the drop down list - see images below. Does anyone know why this might be and how I can fix it?

Image 1 - The attribute table. A hand drawn black rectangle identified the 'Quick Field Calculation Bar'. The hand drawn red ellipse identifies the drop down field list. Note the first column of the tanle is the field 'uuid'.

[image]

Image 2 - The drop down field list. 'uuid' does not appear in the field list.

[image]

[Here is a link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AswVtlUsV-b_lbIkWag8c6oK1aijCA?e=i8JoPp) to a stripped down version of the project in a zipped folder. It's configured as a 'standalone project', i.e. as if it were for QField.

Comment: I just created a simple shapefile with an attribute called "uuid" and it shows up everywhere I expect, so it doesn't seem to be anything special about that name. Any chance you can share the shapefile (or one or two rows of it, maybe redacting or editing anything you can't share?). The only other thought is you are hitting some limit of the dropdown. Weird.

Comment: Hi Spacedman. I've added a link to a redacted project file still showing the issue. I found a work around is simply to open the field calculator tool, and update an existing field. But it's weird the Quick Field calculation tool is not working.

Comment: okay, same behaviour for me as you. I can only think that uuids are things that you shouldn't change because they are meant to be universally unique, so for some reason QGIS is trying to protect you from changing them to anything else... Hmmm...

Comment: Its something to do with the way that layer has been configured in the QGIS project. If I open the shapefile in a fresh QGIS project I can edit the uuid. Must be in the QGIS forms controls dialog - it also creates a couple of extra attributes like vRSA and vDBH. If this is related to QField then maybe that has set up the uuid to be non-editable....

Comment: Thanks. From your prompt, I've found the issue - in Layer_Propoerties_Attribite Form, the editable check box for the widget is not ticked. It seems that if I right-click the layer, and change the data source, this 'Editable' checkbox unchecks itself.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to spacedman....in Layer_Properties_Attribute Form, make sure the widget for your attribute (in this case "uuid") is 'Editable' - see circled checkbox in image below.

[image]